# Dynamically adjusting BatchSize during training of NetChain

Tags: neural-networks

Is it possible to dynamically adjust BatchSize during NetTrain training session? For instance, can I create a schedule to adjust BatchSize based on the training round?

-CJ

Comment: That's no possible now.But you can create multi-NetTrain with different BatchSize

Comment: In theory, you might be able to write a generator to do this. A generator function replaces the data (ie the second argument) in `NetTrain`. This generator function gets two arguments - `BatchSize` and `Round` so something like the following may work: `generator=Function[RandomSample[data, #BatchSize+(10*#Round)]]; NetTrain[net,generator,BatchSize->10]`.